# Who is the copycat in the Hannibal series?

Tags: plot-explanation, hannibal-tv

I have just finished the pilot of Hannibal. My question is: Is Hannibal the copycat? Did he call the killer of empathy or what? Was the killer a cannibal too, given that he returned the victim because of the liver cancer? Or is Hannibal the first killer?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Hannibal is the copycat.  This becomes more explicit later in the series, as it becomes clear that Hannibal is

> taking details of existing cases from his access to FBI agents, and is committing further copycat kills.

The cinematography shows that this is what's happening.  However in S1E10, *Buffet Froid*, we see Hannibal doing this.